# Style on the number of classes?

Tags: css

I have an element that goes from having 2 classes to 3 classes that I want to style when it has 3 classes.

- I can't change the html.
- I can't change the elements classes.
- The classes are generated dynamically so the actual class names change
  from session to session.
- I think the third class is always the toggled class.
- The code is generated by GXT
- I am not allowed to use JavaScript
- The code is frozen(excluding the css) and being discarded in about a month so
  maintenance/best practices do not matter.

Is it possible to do this?

Example of the elements states:

```
<div class="GCGCW0WDLM GCGCW0WDHN" style="">
<div class="GCGCW0WDLM GCGCW0WDHN GCGCW0WDD2" style="">
```

Comment: Do the dynamic class names follow any type of format? For instance, will they always end with a letter? Does the last class always end with a "2"?

Comment: The question is is it possible to style on the total number of classes an element has.

Honestly I'm not sure, I know nothing technical about GXT. I was just given the page and a list of style changes. I think the GCG is some kind of standard string and the 2 might be always their, which would simplify things enormously... Off to see if I can find documentation on how GXT generates it's classes.

Comment: I have a way to check if it's one or more than one class on the element.. But 2 or 3.. That's not easy!

Comment: Have you checked when the div gets the 3 classes the 3rd class is not always the same?

Comment: It seems like you would have to count the number of spaces (spaces + 1 = class count) a `[class]` has in order to get a count of attribute values, then base the style on that. I don't think that exists

Comment: `div[class*=' ']{color:red }` works to check if an element has two or more classes. But I see no way to check between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to select and element based on the number of classes it has with CSS only. (I do not know what GXT is)

Comment: Simplified explaination is GXT is extJS generated using GWT. ext is a javascript/html/css framework and GWT is a google framework for generating web pages using Java.

Comment: @Blue do you have any control of what this GXT produces? If not, then you cannot target the HTML elements you want to via CSS classes  and apparently JavaScript is not an option.

Comment: No control, it's a soon to be retired version of the app they wanted to make look nicer till the new version is ready but the code base is effectively frozen. At this point I'm just going to say not possible to them, which thankfully is an option, but intellectually I couldn't let the problem go without at least seeing if someone knew some kind of trick. I was doing most of my styling based on parent/sibling selectors and nth-type selectors since I have no permanent classes. The code is the ugliest I have ever written but it gets the job done.

Comment: @Blue do you know if the 3rd class always have the "2" at the end?

Comment: @Chun, Not for certain. I was told by the devs that the classes were dynamic but I haven't found any GXT documentation on it. Unfortunately I don't know anything technically about GXT so I'm going with the assumption that the 2 is just a coincidence.

Comment: @Blue That is a fair assessment on your part. Your hands are tied at this point (you can only control the CSS, and cannot target the required element given the dynamic nature of the content provided). Tell your superiors that their request is not currently possible given the above requirements

Comment: Also, implementing _some kind of trick_ always comes with high maintenance. And _high maintenance_ means high cost ;) Superiors hate high cost